# Access variable inside a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to get some data from an external API, but when I loop am trying to push into an empty array it stills empty.
I think it has something to do with accessing the variable inside the callback or the asynchronous behavior.

```
  const ListProducts = asyncHandler(async response => {
  var array = [];
  response.forEach(p => {
    anExternalAPI.showProducts({
      id: p.id,
      callback: res => {
        console.log(res); // showing data
        array.push(res);
      }
    });
  });
  console.log("products: ", array); // it is empty
  return array;
});
```

Comment: "*I think it has something to do with […] the asynchronous behavior*" - precisely that.

Comment: What is the solution please? I tried to put the sync code in setTimeout 1000ms and it worked but I don't think this is a good thing to do.